# Installing R package with libstdc++

Tags: r, package, libstdc++

So here is the thing:

I am trying to install an R package ("Zinba") and I am using OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 and I get the following error with R CMD INSTALL:

```
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘zinba’ ...
** libs
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC   -c aliType.c -o aliType.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c alignAdjust.cc -o alignAdjust.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c analysis.cc -o analysis.o
In file included from analysis.cc:18:
./analysis.h:10:10: fatal error: 'ext/slist' file not found
#include <ext/slist>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [analysis.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘zinba’
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/zinba’
```

I searched about this error and it looks like XCode in Mavericks by default uses libc++ instead of libstdc++ and the recommendation is to compile using "-stdlib=libstdc++"

Now this is third party R package. Can anybody suggest how to compile this package using libstdc++. Also I looked for this library in my machine and I don't I find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the REPL, you can use `withr::with_makevars` to temporarily define environment variables during installation:

```
library(withr)

with_makevars(c(CXXFLAGS = "-stdlib=libstdc++"),
              install.packages("zinba", repos = NULL, type = "source"))
```

Under the hood, it creates a temporary file with the code you provide, sets the environment variable `R_MAKEVARS_USER` to point to it, and then restores defaults when done.